# Валидная строка не может пройти проверку при добавлении к таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql

Структура таблицы seats:

```
CREATE TABLE seats
(   aircraft_code char(3) NOT NULL,         -- код самолета, IATA
    seat_no varchar(4) NOT NULL,            -- Номер места
    fare_condition varchar(10) NOT NULL,        -- Класс обслуживания
    CHECK(fare_condition IN ('Economy', 'Comfort', 'Business')),
    PRIMARY KEY(aircraft_code, seat_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(aircraft_code) 
           REFERENCES aircrafts(aircraft_code)
           ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO seats VALUES ('ABA', '1', 'Business');
```

Получаю вот такое сообщение:

> ОШИБКА:  новая строка в отношении "seats" нарушает
> ограничение-проверку "seats_fare_condition_check" ПОДРОБНОСТИ:
> Ошибочная строка содержит (ABA, 1, Business).

Но вот такую строку таблица принимает без ошибок.

```
INSERT INTO seats VALUES ('DYR', '2', 'Economy');
```

Comment: В валидной строке запроса строковые литералы заключены, как и положено, в кавычки. Чего не наблюдается в процитированном фрагменте проблемного запроса. И, кстати, сообщение об ошибке как-то не очень похоже на сообщение, сгенерированное Постгрессом... по-моему, запрос на него даже не отправляется, ибо не проходит валидацию на стороне клиента.

Comment: Сообщение вполне на postgresql похоже, в исходниках локализации ru.po такие формулировки есть. В описании данных ошибочной строки кавычки не выводятся самой базой. Однако приведённые в вопросе запросы корректны. Проверяйте что у вас ошибка наблюдается именно с этими запросами, а не с какими-то другими. Ну и вместо varchar + check явно просится enum.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас срабатывает `CHECK(fare_condition IN ('Economy', 'Comfort', 'Business'))`. Скорее всего у Вас в `INSERT INTO seats VALUES ('ABA', '1', 'Business');` перемешались кириллица с латиницей перебейте буквы и проверьте.